# how to make radio wave with pi2

Tags: python, pi-2, radio

As pi2 have processing power of 900MHz it can generate upto 250Mhz radio frequency. I have run [fm_transmitter](https://github.com/SandPox/fm_transmitter) on pi2 it was working but only with one song(star_wars.wav) and code was in c++.

Does anybody know how to create radio wave with pi2 in python?(simple code)

How fast i can toggle the gpio pin to generate below digital signal?

[image: dg]

Comment: The most famous example of this is probably "pifm" which has a python port, e.g.: http://www.icrobotics.co.uk/wiki/index.php/Turning_the_Raspberry_Pi_Into_an_FM_Transmitter

Comment: checked pifm it do not work with pi2 :(

Comment: @editinit Hi! I encoutered the same issue with pifm and my RPi 2 and looked around for alternatives which leads me to your thread. Unfortunately your "fm_transmitter" link is broken... Could you update it if possible?

Comment: @Marine1 fm_transmitter wasn't working properly so i used this https://github.com/ChristopheJacquet/PiFmRds , fm_transmitter link is below in lwr20 answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to:
http://www.networkworld.com/article/2999977/opensource-subnet/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-an-fm-radio-transmitter.html

these radio transmitter projects work on the Pi 2:

- https://github.com/markondej/fm_transmitter
- https://github.com/Ginkgo23/PiFmRPi2

Sadly neither of them are in python.

However you could run them from python using the subprocess module.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 1):

Make Magazine created a raspberry pi pirate radio coded in python using a gpio pin and some wire. I haven't tried this project before myself, but since it is from Make Magazine, we can assume in functions properly. This project can be found on this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Make-Magazine/PirateRadio).

Answer (score 0):

For python the pigpio library is probably the best for what you want to accomplish. There is many python examples on the pigpio website.
[check it out](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/)