# PiFM on the Pi 2

Tags: pi-2, pifm

I encountered some issues when trying to create my own FM radio after downloading pifm. Indeed after plugging my own designed antenna, writing on my pi's terminal:

```
sudo ./pifm sound.wav 100.0
```

I used a Raspberry 2 V1.1.

**After setting two radios on this fm wavelength, I don't get the Star Wars soundtrack on them. Can you help me fix this issue?**

I don't think it is an antenna issue as far as I have read that even without antenna it does work. Anyway, here is a picture of its extremity wired to the RPi.

I live in France in a big city.

Here is a picture of the wiring between the foot of the antenna and the component that goes to the 4th pin of the Raspberry.

[image: Picture of the antenna]

And here is a picture of my actual wiring between the component and the 4th pin:

[image: Component to pin wiring]

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=34FNgSLBMJs)

Comment: *"Can you help me fix this issue?*" -> How?  All you've said is it doesn't work.  You don't even mentioned the model of pi; you might want to check on that if it isn't a single core as I believe there are a number of issues with pifm including the fact that it isn't really maintained and may or may not be viable on the 2/3.  TBH most of the stuff we see here about it is not very positive, I think it is more of an experimental oddity than anything practical.   If you don't hear anything at all with the radio tuned and the pi right next to it, I would say it just plain is not doing anything.

Comment: Not sure on your location but USA FM broadcast channels always end in an odd number, so output should be 100.1 or 99.9 for US radios.

Comment: @goldilocks Okay I added my pi version and the serial port I'm using for the antenna. I understand your concerns. I just started with the pifm software but you are the first one I hear that gives bad feedbacks.

Comment: Looks from [this thread](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/42162/5538) like someone else has said they "checked pifm it do not work with pi2".  I haven't used it personally, but if you search around here I think it doesn't come across as hugely practical -- dubious quality, and hogs a processor while running.

Comment: For experimentation it is an interesting project and could lead to interesting possibilities. (sig gen, ref marker, etc)  --   If some one had to have a FM modulator and only a Pi to make it happen then it could serve a purpose, but would be more to my thoughts to head to the thrift store and pick out a old used modulator to interface with or pick up a single chip modulator for a couple bucks.  --  I think I will head off to shop and try it any way.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fork, called PiFmRds. This works on Raspberry Pi 2 and also lets you set the station name, radio text and much more. I've tested it and can pickup a good 500 metres in the car!

https://github.com/ChristopheJacquet/PiFmRds

Comment: God ! Next time I work on it I try this. That sounds appealing !